# Having a constructor causes an error “error: no operator "=" matches these operands”

Tags: c++, constructor

So, I have a `struct` mesh which holds a std::vector of triangles which holds vectors.

```
template <typename T>
struct genericVec3d
{
    T x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 1;

    //////constructors
    genericVec3d() {};
    genericVec3d(T _x, T _y, T _z, T _w) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w) {};
    genericVec3d(T _x, T _y, T _z) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {};
    genericVec3d(const genericVec3d& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z) {};
}; 

typedef genericVec3d<float> vf3d;

struct triangle
{
    vf3d p[3];
};

struct mesh
{
    std::vector<triangle> tris;
};
```

In `main`, if I try to initialize the mesh, with constructor

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mesh sheet;
    sheet.tris = { {1, 1, 1} };
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error message `no operator "=" matches these operands` in line `sheet.tris = { {1, 1, 1} };`

If I comment out all the constructors, it runs fine, but having any constructor causes error and I don't know why. I need those constructors for the rest of my code to function. What can I do?

reproducible code

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct genericVec3d
{
    T x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 1;

    //////constructors
    genericVec3d() {};
    genericVec3d(T _x, T _y, T _z, T _w) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w) {};
    genericVec3d(T _x, T _y, T _z) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {};
    genericVec3d(const genericVec3d& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z) {};
};

typedef genericVec3d<float> vf3d;

struct triangle
{
    vf3d p[3];
};

struct mesh
{
    std::vector<triangle> tris;
};

int main()
{
    mesh sheet;
    sheet.tris = { {1, 1, 1} };
}
```

Comment: The error message should have told you exactly what operands are being passed to `operator=`.  You likely need to add some additional constructors and assignment operators to `triangle` and `genericVec3d` to handle [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (`std::vector` already has them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more `{}`'s, because what you are doing just now is creating a vector with a single triangle, and that triangle is trying to set 3 variables when there is only 1 (the array).

```cpp
    // what you have
    sheet.tris = { // vector of triangles
        { // triangle
            1, // meant to be array of vf3ds, but it's instead an int
            1, // ?
            1  // ?
        }
    };
    // what you need
    sheet.tris = { // vector of triangles
        { // triangle
            { // array of vf3ds
                { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f } // vf3ds
                // ideally two more vf3ds should be here,
                // because triangle stores an array of 3 vf3ds
            }
        }
    };
```